# listening to a socket with socket.io-redis module

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

With `socket.io-redis` module we can easily `emit/broadcast` message with `saved-socket-id`.

```
io.to(socket-id-from-redis).emit('serverEvent', "some message");
```

On the otherhand, what's the best way for listening to the socket with out any  extra/external redis sub/pub clients.

When I initialized `socket-io.redis` module, I had configured a subscriber with return_buffers: **true**, I think module solves it behind the scenes but I couldn't find any examples.

Is there a smooth way to do that with `socket.io-redis` module ? Or each clusters socket listeners must publish messages and i must manually subscribe'em from other clusters ?

Thank you.